# Decode H264 From Array of Integers

Tags: java, h.264, jcodec

I'm trying to decode a H264 raw protocol from a camera but I'm having some problems using the Jcodec H264Decoder. I receive an array of integers with the information from the camera. Below a sample of the data:

array: 00 00 01 FD 00 00 14 69 00 00 00 01 61 E4 80 6F D3 5B 76 97 DF 04 3A EF 54 97 0E D9 F5...more

The code I'm using is :

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap( Utils.intArrayToByteArray(array, arraySize) );
bb.rewind();
// Create a buffer to hold the output picture which is big enough
Picture outBuffer = Picture.create( 1920, 1088, ColorSpace.YUV420 );
Picture pic = _decoder.decodeFrame( bb, outBuffer.getData() );
BufferedImage bufferedImage = JCodecUtil.toBufferedImage( pic );
```

When I try to run it, I get NullPointerException as follow:

Exception in thread "Thread-6" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jcodec.codecs.h264.H264Decoder$FrameDecoder.decodeFrame(H264Decoder.java:82)
    at org.jcodec.codecs.h264.H264Decoder.decodeFrame(H264Decoder.java:61)
    at br.com.grupogiga.security.xm.player.jcodec.JCodecPlayer.test_readNals(JCodecPlayer.java:122)
    at br.com.grupogiga.security.xm.player.jcodec.JCodecPlayer.processNAL(JCodecPlayer.java:69)
    at br.com.grupogiga.security.xm.player.XMH264Player$1$2.NALArrived(XMH264Player.java:143)
    at br.com.grupogiga.security.xm.protocols.ProtocolParser.emitNALArrived(ProtocolParser.java:408)
    at br.com.grupogiga.security.xm.protocols.ProtocolParser.run(ProtocolParser.java:121)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

What I'm doing wrong ?? How do I decode the data using JCodec ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That looks to me like no fault of your own, but rather an internal JCodec bug. You can check through the issues on [their issue tracker](https://github.com/jcodec/jcodec/issues) to see if this is known. If not, you may want to create an issue for this. Provide the stack trace and as much information as you can.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that you're getting an int array? It would appear to be a byte array from your print-out. I would suggest not doing the array conversion and also not doing a rewind; ByteBuffer.wrap will already put you at position 0 in the buffer. The 00 00 01 is a start of NAL marker and the FD is the NAL type btw.