# Red and green lines on my output using Jcodec

Tags: java, h.264, jcodec

I've posted an issue to the [jcodec tracker](https://github.com/jcodec/jcodec/issues/60) about this problem I'm having with jcodec, but I assume this will get more coverage if I ask here as well. Briefly, I have h.264 encoded data and I am getting YUV420P raw data using the Jcodec library. Once I have the raw frame data, it contains red and green horizontal lines; does anyone have any idea as to why this is happening? Is my raw data malformed in some way? Did I copy the bytes incorrectly? Is this actually a decoder fault?

Here's what the yuv420p data looks like when converted into a png:
[image]

Related SO questions:

- [Get YUV bytes from jcodec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272726/get-yuv420-bytes-from-jcodec-picture/26340019#26340019)
- [Decode h264 from int array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21163498/decode-h264-from-array-of-integers)